# installing ipython hash error

Tags: pip, ipython

I am getting following error

> THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE

while doing `pip install ipython`

Searching online, I found some users have success using `--no-cache-dir` but I had no luck.

Any suggestion on fixing this issue would be appreciated

Complete paste:

> as-MacBook-Pro:~ a$ pip install ipython Collecting ipython   Using
>   cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/19/aadde98d6bde1667d0bf431fb2d22451f880aaa373e0a241c7e7cb5815a0/ipython-5.7.0-py2-none-any.whl
>   Collecting traitlets>=4.2 (from ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d6/abcb22de61d78e2fc3959c964628a5771e47e7cc60d53e9342e21ed6cc9a/traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting decorator (from ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/bb/a24838832ba35baf52f32ab1a49b906b5f82fb7c76b2f6a7e35e140bac30/decorator-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/57/4d9c9e3ae9a255cd4e1106bb57e24056d3d0709fc01b2e3e345898e49d5b/simplegeneric-0.8.1.zip
>   Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7"
>   (from ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/cd/1750d6c35fe86d35f8562091737907f234b78fdffab42b29c72b1dd861f4/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pygments (from ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/ee/b6e02dc6529e82b75bb06823ff7d005b141037cb1416b10c6f00fc419dca/Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" (from ipython)   Using
>   cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/a9/7985e6a53402f294c8f0e8eff3151a83f1fb901fa92909bb3ff29b4d22af/appnope-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" (from ipython)   Using
>   cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/e6/b5a1de8b0cc4e07ca1b305a4fcc3f9806025c1b651ea302646341222f88b/pexpect-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pickleshare (from ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/17/daa142fc9be6b76f26f24eeeb9a138940671490b91cb5587393f297c8317/pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4 (from ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/b0/1a6c262da35c779dd79550137aa7c298a424987240a28792ec5ccf48f848/prompt_toolkit-1.0.15-py2-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from ipython) (18.5) Collecting pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or
>   python_version == "3.3" (from ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/a7/9f8d84f31728d78beade9b1271ccbfb290c41c1e4dc13dbd4997ad594dcd/pathlib2-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting ipython-genutils (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)   Using
>   cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/bc/9bd3b5c2b4774d5f33b2d544f1460be9df7df2fe42f352135381c347c69a/ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: six in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython) (1.4.1) Collecting enum34;
>   python_version == "2.7" (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/db/e56e6b4bbac7c4a06de1c50de6fe1ef3810018ae11732a50f15f62c7d050/enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
>   Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect; sys_platform !=
>   "win32"->ipython)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/29/605c2cc68a9992d18dada28206eeada56ea4bd07a239669da41674648b6f/ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython)
>   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9f/526a6947247599b084ee5232e4f9190a38f398d7300d866af3ab571a5bfe/wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting scandir; python_version < "3.5" (from pathlib2;
>   python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython)   Using
>   cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/bb/e541b74230bbf7a20a3949a2ee6631be299378a784f5445aa5d0047c192b/scandir-1.7.tar.gz
>   THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If
>   you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes.
>   Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have
>   tampered with them.
>       simplegeneric>0.8 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/57/4d9c9e3ae9a255cd4e1106bb57e24056d3d0709fc01b2e3e345898e49d5b/simplegeneric-0.8.1.zip#sha256=dc972e06094b9af5b855b3df4a646395e43d1c9d0d39ed345b7393560d0b9173
>   (from ipython):
>           Expected sha256 dc972e06094b9af5b855b3df4a646395e43d1c9d0d39ed345b7393560d0b9173
>                Got        01eda95e2448e83d00402a9c32bb4f72f6c26e6e7e051e1c98af79eab72b3b4d

Comment: If there's other better place to post this question, let me know

Comment: So what is the output when you use `--no-cache-dir`?

Comment: its the exact same output

Comment: It shouldn't be because `pip` doesn't use cached wheels when `--no-cache-dir` used.

Comment: @hoefling: https://pastebin.com/veRLZrL9